# Triggers for build completion not kicking off pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Hoping someone could help me out with an issue I'm running into.  I have 4 different pipelines set up with the first triggering the second upon build completion and so on down the line.  The triggers are not kicking off after the previous pipeline steps build completion as they are supposed to do so.  THey're also all on the same branch so i'm at a loss as to what to do.  Any ideas?  Classic pipeline not a YAML

[image: picture of my pipeline trigger setup]

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that your `MPV Automated Testing Step 1` pipeline runs successfully, because a failed run will not trigger the Build completion trigger.

I tested two pipelines on the same branch. On my side, build completion trigger works well.

[image]

In addition, there is a recently event of availability degradation of Azure DevOps, which could affected these services, and it has been resolved. If you want to know more information, please click [here](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history). You can try again to see if the problem still exists.